# Unix Shell in C Pipe prob

Tags: c, shell, unix, fork, pipe

I am currently working on a unix shell c. My problem is the pipe, I have traveled many forums and I can not solve it.
I go through a temporary file.

Thank you in advance.

Code here : http://pastebin.com/cuGbJ6XD

Comment: Did you have a question?

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at "man 2 pipe", "man 2 dup2" and "man 3 popen".  The first two are what you need, the last is a sub-set of what you are trying to build but should give ideas.

Basic steps
    - fork
    - create the pipe
    - fork again
       * on one side of the fork, close stdout (1) and dup2 the pipe output to 1
       * on the other side of the fork, close stdin (0) and dup2 pipe input to 0
       * on both sides, close the original pipe descriptors
    - on each side of the fork, exec the correct programs.

Been a while, but that is what I remember.